# Kindly guide me what i am doing wrong in BETWEEN query

Tags: mysql

i am trying to run the below script

```
SELECT field_value 
  FROM jos_js_res_record_values jrv 
 INNER 
  JOIN jos_js_res_record jr 
    ON jrv.record_id = jr.id 
 where field_id = 49 
 WHERE jr.ctime BETWEEN '2011-21-03' AND '2012-01-03' 
 ORDER BY jr.user_id ASC;
```

but that shows the below error

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE jr.ctime BETWEEN '2011-21-03' AND '2012-01-03' ORDER BY jr.user_id ASC ' at line 1

**Kindly guide me what i am doing wrong in it..**

Comment: You have two `WHERE` in your query. A typo?

Comment: It would be a really, really good idea to qualify the `field_id` column with the table alias...  i.e. `jr.field_id` or `jrv.field_id`, for whichever table that column is coming from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are saying `WHERE` twice.  The second `WHERE` needs to be an `AND`.